# How can I resolve Copy-Item error 'file is being used by another process' when copying eventlog in PowerShell remoting?

Tags: powershell-remoting

I'm new to PowerShell. I'm trying to copy eventlog from a remote computer. But I'm getting the following error.
*Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Application.evtx'
because it is being used by another process.*

Here is my script:

```
`#List of computer need to copy to
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\mypc\Documents\PowerShell\computersList.txt"
$cred = Get-Credential


foreach($server in $servers){
    if ($server -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME){$path = "C:"}
    $eventlog = "$path\C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs"
    
    $source = "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Application.evtx"
    
    $mdy = (Get-Date).AddDays($i).ToString("MM-dd-yy")
    
    $Dest = Split-Path -Path "C:\Users\mypc\Documents\PowerShell\Logs\$mdy" -Parent
    
    New-Item -Path $Dest -ItemType Directory -Force
    
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred 
    
    Copy-Item -Path  $source -Destination $Dest -FromSession $session -Force

}`
```

Trying to copy event log with admin cred.